# How can I insert an array as a column in SQL?

Tags: sql, select, multiple-columns, sql-insert

I have an array that is a large set of numbers that i'd like to use as a column when adding to a table.  I'd like to also add specific values while doing this, and i'm unsure how.  I'm new to SQL so any help would be appreciated!

So basically I have this:

```
INSERT INTO Staff_test (patient_id, 
start_date, staff_id, role, is_primary, orig_user_id, orig_entry_chron, 
user_id, entry_chron)

SELECT (patient_id, '2017-06-24', '40001704', 'BILLING', 'Y', 
'RENEGADE', '2017-06-24', 'RENEGADE', '2017-06-24'); 

FROM Staff_test
patient_id in ('123', '124', '543', '654', '328')
```

I know i'm doing things wrong here but I'm not sure of the correct way.  To clarify i'm hoping to use the patient id as the column value.  So it should result something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tso79.png).

Please help!

Comment: Is your array of values able to be passed in as a comma separated list? i.e. '123,124,543,654,328' and what version of SQL server are you using?

Comment: Are we to assume that the ids listed in your array do not already exist in your Staff_test table?

Answer (score 0):

INSERT INTO
Staff_test (patient_id
, start_date 
, staff_id, role
, is_primary
, orig_user_id
, orig_entry_chron
, user_id, entry_chron)

SELECT (patient_id, '2017-06-24', '40001704', 'BILLING', 'Y', 
'RENEGADE', '2017-06-24', 'RENEGADE', '2017-06-24')
FROM Staff_test
where 
patient_id in ('123', '124', '543', '654', '328')

if is_primary is_boolen then use 1 instate of 'y'
if prent_id is int then use int vale like 123, 124, not '123','124'

Comment: I get an "Incorrect syntax near ','."  error when I run that.